# How does the "posts with unsourced content may be edited or deleted" annotation get added?

Tags: support

Referring to

[image]

How does this get added to an answer?? I ***love*** this. Is it only done by moderators?

Unsourced BS answers (UBSA) are the biggest problem on the site today IMHO.

Comment: As Glorfindel said, just flag anything that needs a post notice. I periodically go through old notice-annotated posts to delete if they haven't been fixed. Just finished doing a bunch right now, actually!

Comment: I created a query that shows all the answers without hyperlinks: https://data.stackexchange.com/space/query/1294453/answers-without-hyperlinks. This may be helpful for identifying low quality answers. Not all of them are necessarily poorly referenced, but the absence of hyperlinks is certainly one potential indicator.

Comment: @called2voyage a good answer could certainly be calculation-based  and not have references, but that's a very interesting list.

Comment: Yes, or have textual references to offline resources, but it looks like around a quarter of these are negative scoring, so there's probably lots that are poorly referenced.

Comment: :( I see myself on the list. Bad answerer! Bad!

Comment: Stack Exchange does encourage rough answers from experts who don't have time for a rigorous one, but my rule of thumb is if someone challenges the information it needs to be edited to address that or otherwise removed.

Comment: Well, this is another problem that's concentrated around certain users. Just 10 users have created over a third of the no-hyperlink answers on this site.

Comment: @called2voyage color me unsurprised.

Comment: On closer inspection, the answers of four of those users seem to be unproblematic, but the other 6 definitely are on shakier footing. Most of the six get about 1/4 to 1/3 of their rep from their no-hyperlink answers, but two of them actually get well over half of their rep from those answers (one gets about 2/3 and the other over 3/4!!).

Comment: @called2voyage thanks for looking into it. Intution is always questionable but that also matches pretty well with what I've seen. it's chronic with a few individuals.

Comment: somewhat related [Are unsourced yet “authoritative-sounding” answers proper here?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/938/12102) Using the same naming convention I suppose they would be USyASAs or USASAs?

Comment: Interesting, I have 10 answers without links. one is crap and really should go, a few others could use supportive sources for their numbers and formulas like the rocket equation, and some others use textual references only. Its definitely being interesting looking at my answers in that way. We really should strife for well-sourced answers.

Comment: @Polygnome IMHO textual references = fine, calculations = fine. So just looking for links is going to result in some false UBSA positives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a so-called [post notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186087/295232). They can only be added (and removed) by ♦ moderators. Space Exploration only has the three 'standard' answer notices, as can be seen in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/space/query/1240483/answer-notices).

I'm a moderator on three other sites in the network and regularly apply answer notices when I see a low quality answer (often after it has been *flagged* as Very Low Quality) of which I think it *might* be able to be edited into a proper answer. I guess you could use a custom moderator flag asking to apply a post notice, but I haven't seen anybody do that so far and I'm not sure what the moderators here think about this.

Comment: Yes, please use flags asking for post notices!

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! Flagging UBSAs for moderator attention may be an issue on this site though.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's not an issue. If you're concerned about the volume, don't be. The flag volume is not currently a problem at the moment.

Comment: @called2voyage but....one of the moderators is one of the leading culprits.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have put post notices on moderator posts before and deleted their posts.

Comment: @OrganicMarble And I'm happy to accept correction on my own posts as well. I usually don't handle flags on my own posts. I'll ask one of the other mods to look.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Also, if you feel a flag was not handled appropriately, you can always bring the issue to meta for extra accountability, and even involve the CM team, if necessary.

Comment: @OrganicMarble You know, you could have just left a comment on the post asking for some sources...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I got tired of doing that.  Just from the first page of answers: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46652/6944, https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46637/6944,  https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46460/6944, https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46424/6944  Every time I read one of these, I'm thinking "Who says so?"

Comment: Fair enough, I could stand to source things a bit better...